# SearchView close button alignment

Tags: android, uisearchbar

I implemented standard SearchView. But there is weird space on right side of SearchView, when search is active (see picture). Source code is [here](https://github.com/niravkalola/Android-Searchview-Example). How to align close button to right side? I tested that on Android 7. I have to write more text here, but there is no reason for that.

[image]

**Menu:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.android.nigeriaexams.ui.SettingsFragment">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</menu>
```

**Activity**:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    //*** setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener ***
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchQuery) {
            myAppAdapter.filter(searchQuery.toString().trim());
            listView.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    });

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when collapsed
            return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when expanded
            return true;  // Return true to expand action view
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 10):

`searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

This sets the close icon as far right as possible. I had the same problem when running on a tablet device, the close icon was in the middle of the toolbar, now it is on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your Images in toolbar try following code. you dont need menu.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/camera"
                        android:src="@drawable/camera"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/search"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/search"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/search"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </RelativeLayout>



        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I believe that this code will not solve problem, because it add more icons, but not align correctly close button for opened search view.